# $\alpha > \sin(\alpha)$, $\alpha \leqq \sin(\alpha)$ - can we find intervals on which it it true?

Tags: trigonometry

Given angle is in radians, how can we find intervals on which all such inequalities hold true?

$\alpha > \sin(\alpha)$, $\alpha < \sin(\alpha)$, $\alpha \leqq \sin(\alpha)$, $\alpha \geqq \sin(\alpha)$

And all the values where $\alpha = \sin(\alpha)$

Plus, same for $\cos, \tan$.

P.S. I understand that $\alpha \leqq 1$ for sine and cosine. But for $\tan$ and $\alpha < 1$ for sine and cosine I don't have a clue.

Comment: For $x>0$, $x>\sin x$ and for $x<0$, $x < \sin x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Leibniz test, for $0<x<2$,
$$
x-\frac{x^3}6\le\sin x\le x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}<x
$$
and for $x\ge 2>1\ge \sin x$ is trivially true. Similar holds for the negative half axis.

Thus your question about the sine has a very simple answer.

---

For the cosine and tangent these equations are transcendental, thus have no nice solutions. The same goes for any modification of the sine question, for instance asking when $α\geqq 2\sin α$